# Save selected dropdown value to JSON

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

I want to save a value of the selected element of a dropdown to a JSON file.

```html
<td contenteditable=true bgcolor="#F4F2F2">
    <select>
       <option value="default">${list.days}</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

```js
function(i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'), status = $tds.eq(0).text();
    console.log(status)
    json = json + " {\"deviceType\": \"" + $tds.eq(1).text()+ "\"," + "\"days\": \"" + $tds.eq(2).text()+ "\"},";});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not attempting to create your own JSON string from scratch. Instead, use the JSON.stringify() method:

```
/* Create a new object from scratch to convert to JSON later */
obj = {          
    deviceType: $tds.eq(1).find("select")[0].val(),
    days: $tds.eq(2).find("select")[0].val()
};

/* Stringify your object */
json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

This code example assumes that $tds.eq(1) and $tds.eq(2) each contain a single select element.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Prasad.Chitti. Don't forget to "accept" my answer if you feel it put you on the right path :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can send the value to PHP and save it

```
$('.input').change(function(){
  //Save value of this dropdown menu
  $value = $(this).val();

  //AJAX the value to the PHP

  $.post('balbal.php',{
    value: $value
  });


});
```

Comment: I've mentioned here as Java.

Answer (score 0):

Got it Using @ohio818 inputs did following changes to JSON object

```
json = json + " {\"deviceType\": \"" + $tds.eq(1).text()+ "\"," +"\"days\":\""+ $tds.eq(2).find("select").val()+ "\"},";
```